# Java generate only SVG with Batik without any DOCTYPE

Tags: java, svg, batik

I'm trying to generate svg that I will later use for PDF generation from HTML file. I use OpenHtmlToPdf that can put inline svg to pdf along with other html code.

The problem is that Batik example generates the svg along with `<DOCTYPE>` and `<?xml>` tags.

And I want only the `<svg>` tag and it's contents.

This is the code I use for svg generation:

```
public class TestSVGGen {

public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(10, 10, 400, 5));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(10, 15, 10, 125));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(110, 15, 10, 125));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(210, 15, 10, 125));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(310, 15, 10, 125));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(400, 15, 10, 125));
    g2d.drawString("test",20,150);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Get a DOMImplementation.
    DOMImplementation domImpl =
            GenericDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();

    // Create an instance of org.w3c.dom.Document.
    String svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    Document document = domImpl.createDocument(svgNS, "svg", null);

    // Create an instance of the SVG Generator.
    SVGGraphics2D svgGenerator = new SVGGraphics2D(document);

    // Ask the test to render into the SVG Graphics2D implementation.
    TestSVGGen test = new TestSVGGen();
    test.paint(svgGenerator);

    // Finally, stream out SVG to the standard output using
    // UTF-8 encoding.
    boolean useCSS = true; // we want to use CSS style attributes
    Writer out = new FileWriter("test-svg.xhtml");
    svgGenerator.stream(out, useCSS);
}
```

}

This is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN'
          'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="fill-opacity:1; color-rendering:auto; color-interpolation:auto; text-rendering:auto; stroke:black; stroke-linecap:square; stroke-miterlimit:10; shape-rendering:auto; stroke-opacity:1; fill:black; stroke-dasharray:none; font-weight:normal; stroke-width:1; font-family:'Dialog'; font-style:normal; stroke-linejoin:miter; font-size:12px; stroke-dashoffset:0; image-rendering:auto;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
><!--Generated by the Batik Graphics2D SVG Generator--><defs id="genericDefs"
  /><g
  ><g
    ><rect x="10" width="400" height="5" y="10" style="stroke:none;"
      /><rect x="10" width="10" height="125" y="15" style="stroke:none;"
      /><rect x="110" width="10" height="125" y="15" style="stroke:none;"
      /><rect x="210" width="10" height="125" y="15" style="stroke:none;"
      /><rect x="310" width="10" height="125" y="15" style="stroke:none;"
      /><rect x="400" width="10" height="125" y="15" style="stroke:none;"
      /><text x="20" xml:space="preserve" y="150" style="stroke:none;"
      >test</text
    ></g
  ></g
></svg
>
```

This is what I need to get:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="fill-opacity:1; color-rendering:auto; color-interpolation:auto; text-rendering:auto; stroke:black; stroke-linecap:square; stroke-miterlimit:10; shape-rendering:auto; stroke-opacity:1; fill:black; stroke-dasharray:none; font-weight:normal; stroke-width:1; font-family:'Dialog'; font-style:normal; stroke-linejoin:miter; font-size:12px; stroke-dashoffset:0; image-rendering:auto;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
><!--Generated by the Batik Graphics2D SVG Generator--><defs id="genericDefs"
  /><g
  ><g
    ><rect x="10" width="400" height="5" y="10" style="stroke:none;"
      /><rect x="10" width="10" height="125" y="15" style="stroke:none;"
      /><rect x="110" width="10" height="125" y="15" style="stroke:none;"
      /><rect x="210" width="10" height="125" y="15" style="stroke:none;"
      /><rect x="310" width="10" height="125" y="15" style="stroke:none;"
      /><rect x="400" width="10" height="125" y="15" style="stroke:none;"
      /><text x="20" xml:space="preserve" y="150" style="stroke:none;"
      >test</text
    ></g
  ></g
></svg
>
```

I tried to pass the SVGGraphics2D an empty document instance, but that didn't work:

```
public class TestSVGGen {

public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(10, 10, 400, 5));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(10, 15, 10, 125));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(110, 15, 10, 125));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(210, 15, 10, 125));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(310, 15, 10, 125));
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(400, 15, 10, 125));
    g2d.drawString("test",20,150);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document document = newEmptyDocument();

    // Create an instance of the SVG Generator.
    SVGGraphics2D svgGenerator = new SVGGraphics2D(document);

    // Ask the test to render into the SVG Graphics2D implementation.
    TestSVGGen test = new TestSVGGen();
    test.paint(svgGenerator);

    // Finally, stream out SVG to the standard output using
    // UTF-8 encoding.
    boolean useCSS = true; // we want to use CSS style attributes
    Writer out = new FileWriter("test-svg.xhtml");
    svgGenerator.stream(out, true);
}

public static Document newEmptyDocument() {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = null;
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    Document ret;

    try {
        factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ret = builder.newDocument();

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I found that on google: http://batik.2283329.n4.nabble.com/Removing-DOCTYPE-in-the-SVG-XML-td2979102.html#a2979105 - Seems that the transcoder API does the job

Comment: Having a hard time to make it work. But I think I'll just use substring to remove everything before <svg. Thanks though